# How to pull out the underlying query syntax being used by dataset?

Tags: dataset, query

Consider the following dataset.

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]
```

If I use the lookup syntax of the dataset like following it creates an equivalent `Query` syntax which is compiled and then applied to the dataset.

```
titanic[Select[#survived == True && #age > 60 &], {"class", "sex"}] // InputForm
```

If you look at the input syntax above you can see the `TypeSystem` being used for storage and also the `Query` used to arrive at the current dataset from the previous one.

I want to extract the `Query` being used. I tried the following with no success.

```
query=First@Cases[%, x_Query :> x, \[Infinity], Heads -> True]
```

Once the `Query` is extracted I can just use `Normal[query]` to get the optimized version.

Can someone help me get out the `Query` from the `Dataset`. I know it is trivial in this case but I want to use this as a base to work with more complex queries and have a way to track previous datasets using their `"ID"s` and connecting `Query` like a `Graph` with `ID` as `Vertices` and `Query` as `Edges` in a workflow diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a probably an internal function that can extract this information, but if not, you could use the following function to do so:

```
extractDatasetInformation[ds_Dataset] := Block[{Dataset = Inactive[Dataset]},
    Uncompress[Compress[ds]][[3]]
]
```

Your example:

```
q = titanic[Select[#survived == True && #age > 60 &], {"class", "sex"}];

extractDatasetInformation[q]
%["Origin"]
```

> <|"Origin" -> 
>     HoldComplete[
>      Query[Select[#survived == True && #age > 60 &], {"class", "sex"}][
>       Dataset`DatasetHandle[263616672941144]]], "ID" -> 278717777953890|>
>
> HoldComplete[
>    Query[Select[#survived == True && #age > 60 &], {"class", "sex"}][
>     Dataset`DatasetHandle[263616672941144]]]

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why did you compress the inactive `Dataset` expression and uncompress it before extracting the part?

Answer (score 6):

We can extract the query from the dataset object through pattern-matching:

```
datasetQuery[HoldPattern[Dataset[_,_,KeyValuePattern["Origin"->HoldComplete[query_[___]]]]]] := query
```

Then:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];

ds = titanic[Select[#survived == True && #age > 60 &], {"class", "sex"}];

datasetQuery[ds]

(* Query[Select[#survived == True && #age > 60 &], {"class", "sex"}] *)
```

Beware that this relies upon undocumented internal structure for `Dataset` objects which may change between releases.  The exhibited pattern is current for Version 12.